# Which algorithm is implemented in cv::floodfill

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Which algorithm is implemented in cv::floodfill? Does anyone know the paper or an other reference?

Comment: OpenCV is developed via Github. You can check out their code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b46719b0931b256ab68d5f833b8fadd83737ddd1/modules/imgproc/src/floodfill.cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm employed to mark a region of similar pixels is called [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), hence the name of the OpenCV method. Flood fill can be implemented recursively or iteratively. The iterative approach can push pixel coordinates into a queue or onto a stack. The order of exploration doesn't matter because in all cases you end up visiting every pixel that is connected to the starting pixel. The important thing is to mark the pixels that you have visited so that you don't explore them again.